# Best practices place to put URL that configs my app?

Tags: qt, configuration

We have a Qt app that when it starts tries to connect to a servlet to get config parameters that it needs to keep running.

The URL may change frequently because we have to test the application in several environments. Right now (as a temporary solution) the URL is a constant in source code, but it is a little bit ugly.

Where is the best place to mainting this URL, so that we do not need to change the source code every time I want to change the environment target?

In a database table maybe (my application uses a SQLite DB), in a settings file, or in some other way?

Thank you for you replies.

Comment: I would do it in a settings file, if you don't have to worry about someone abusing the URL. But still you can do some kind on encoding in these cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of options:

1. Hard coded (like you have already)
2. Run-time user input
3. [Command line arguments](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#accessing-command-line-arguments)
4. [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html)
5. Read from a bespoke file as text.

I would think option 3 would be the most simple to implement without being intrusive, but it does depend on what kind of application you have.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the list of url in a document, e.g. a XML, stored in a central, well known place, e.g. a known web server, and hardcode the url of the known place in the app.

The list could then be edited externally without recompiling your app;

The app would at startup download and parse the list, pointing to the right servlet based upon an environment specified as a command line parameter.